# Android: How to restrict specific apps

Tags: android, service

In my app, I need to block sms, email and phone. I am not detecting for `incoming or outgoing calls or sms`. Simply, I have a service which will run in background and check if any of three processes is running. If they are running then my activity will open up when user clicks on dialer or sms app. So far, what I have tried, I am posting below:

**Service Class**

```
public class DialerService extends Service {
ActivityManager am;
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> mAppProcessInfosList;
private Runnable myRunnable;
boolean threadDone = true;
Handler mHandler;
boolean isLockedAppRunning = false;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

public void onCreate() {
    am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    mAppProcessInfosList = new ArrayList<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo>();
    mHandler = new Handler();
    Log.v("Dialer Service", "onCreate called");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    myRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            isRestrictedAppRunning();
        }
    };

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (threadDone) {

                try {
                    mHandler.post(myRunnable);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void isRestrictedAppRunning() {
    mAppProcessInfosList = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (int i = 0; i < mAppProcessInfosList.size(); i++) {
        if (mAppProcessInfosList.get(i).processName
                .equals("com.android.phone")
                || mAppProcessInfosList.get(i).processName
                        .equals("com.android.email")
                || mAppProcessInfosList.get(i).processName
                        .equals("com.android.mms")) {
            isLockedAppRunning = true;
            Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    TestActivity.class);
            dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.threadDone = false;
}
}
```

This code is working but it has following issue:

It blocks all the apps, while my requirement is to restrict only those apps which I have listed to block. For e.g., if I am blocking phone and sms, my activity should open only on click of dialer and sms app, and not when I click on maps.

I am not getting how to do this.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the best place to look for a developer to contract work out to.

Comment: @mah And I am also not here to sign contract for my work, just discussing a problem what I faced, so that others can give their opinion, and help me to point out where I missed.

Comment: Please read the Stack Overflow faq at http://stackoverflow.com/faq and please understand that this is _not_ a discusson forum. Obviously you're not here looking to hire a contractor, however your question is (in my opinion, others may disagree) well too in depth for posting here.

Comment: I always provide enough details so that people here can get a clear picture. If you are taking it in a wrong way, then, extremely sorry, thats not my problem at all.

Comment: I agree you've provided enough details for people to understand what you're trying to do. That fact is not enough to claim your question is sufficiently narrowly scoped, and the lack of answers seems to suggest that if you actually want an answer, then it is your problem after all.

Comment: OK,Cease fire...We are not fighting in a battle. Can you please suggest me something?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 0):

When you detect that your blacklisted app is coming up, you need to bring down the running activity. A background service/thread will best handle the activity monitor. There are other internal methods using IActivityWatcher but the internal interface and related hidden APIs are subject to deprecation. I believe it is already deprecated in JB.